# Parse.com Request's count

Tags: parse-platform

If you run a ParseQuery returning 1000 records, it counts as a request only? Or 1000 requests?

Comment: A request for 1000 objects is 1 request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wain pointed out, 1 query (that returns 1,000 records) is still only 1 request.

Source: https://www.parse.com/questions/cloud-code-limitation-and-api-calls-count